# How to configure SSL on Netty Server for Playframework?

Tags: ssl, playframework

```
    javaOptions ++= Seq(
  "-Dhttps.port=9443",
  "-Dhttps.keyStore=conf/newjkskeystore.jks",
  "-Dhttps.keyStorePassword=mypassword")
```

I have a set of certificates .crt(Wildcard). I tried to generate the .jks file but I think that I am doing something wrong. I will put in production on Windows Server that it is running SSL but on IIS Apache. I put to run play on NettyServer and I would like to keep like that. Is that any magic way to fix this issue?

Comment: What have you tried? What have you noticed? What's the error?

Comment: I just tried to run now with with the reference to the jks in application.conf and play keep generating another p.c.s.s.DefaultSSLEngineProvider - Using generated key with self signed certificate for HTTPS. This should not be used in production. And yesterday I got errors about cipher ...

Comment: I got some success on development mode after follow this tutorial https://www.tbs-certificates.co.uk/FAQ/en/626.html but now I getting error in production mode when I put to run the application. Localhost it is working well but in production there is an error - Error injecting constructor....key store file name.jks does not exist! :(

Comment: I am stuck again :( I couldn't run on production mode yet. I am getting this error - Error injecting constructor, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement
failed: Key store file conf/mykeystore.jks does not exist!

Comment: Any idea???????

Comment: as alternative you can run nginx as reverse proxy with ssl